# $C([-1,1])$ is not a reflexive spac. With hint.

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm asked to show that $C([-1,1])$ is not a reflexive space. In the problem there is a hint saying:

> First prove that for every normed vector space $(V, \|\cdot\|_V)$ we have $\|x\| = \sup_{\|x*\|_{V^*}=1} |x^*(x)|$. Consider the linear functional $x^* : C([-1,1]) \to \mathbb{C}, x^*(x) = \int_{-1}^{0} x(t) dt - \int_{0}^{1} x(t) dt.$

But I don't even know how to prove the first claim $\|x\| = \sup_{\|x*\|_{V^*}=1}$? Also I dont see where this hint will lead me to, will it end up in a contradiction?

Comment: In a reflexive space, every functional attains its norm on the unit ball. The first claim may be proven via Hahn-Banach (one of the inequality directions is easy, the other required HB)

Comment: So I will end up in a contradiction saying that there is no $x_0 \in B_0$ s.t $|x^*(x_0)| = ||x^*||$? @Nitin

Comment: That is correct.